# Cannot import name 'webdriver' from Appium on Python

Tags: python, appium, python-appium

I want to use the Appium Python Client to automate testing the apps and have already downloaded the client using pip, but when I follow the docs listed here: https://pypi.org/project/Appium-Python-Client/ , I run into a problem where I can't import WebDriver from Appium despite a Webdriver folder existing inside the Appium package in Lib/site-packages

The answers provided on StackOverflow regarding this issue have not helped me as none of their solutions worked for me, so I want to know what the issue is and how to solve it. Also, I am using Windows and Python 3.7.2 if that is somehow related. Thanks in advance.

```
import unittest
from appium import webdriver

desired_caps = {}
desired_caps['platformName'] = 'Android'
desired_caps['platformVersion'] = '9'
desired_caps['automationName'] = 'uiautomator2'
desired_caps['deviceName'] = 'OnePlox'
desired_caps['app'] = 'C:/Users/hadin/Desktop/ApiDemos-debug.apk'

driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
```

Comment: What Error is occurring or what behavior is your program exhibiting that you want to change and what did you expect?
For more info have a look at [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @LinFelix the error is occurring on the second line when I go to import webdriver from appium. It says "ImportError: cannot import name 'webdriver' from 'appium'". I am using the code as described here on github: https://github.com/appium/python-client#usage

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the [appium-doctor](https://github.com/appium/appium-doctor)?

This would help you to identify whether the configuration files are correct or not